# Node.js Heroku deploy error 503

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, favicon

I am trying to deploy a Node.js application to Heroku via a Github repo. It is successfully building the app, but when it deploys there is an Application Error -- and the console reports a 503 error

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 503(Service unavailable)"

The resource it is looking for is a "favicon.ico" file. I tried putting it in the root directory, in a ./public folder, and inside a ./static folder inside app/.

This is strange because I wasn't attempting to reference this file at all in my initial deployment (this is for a class project, and I am trying to set stuff up) and this error still occurred then. I am feeling like Heroku is expecting this file to be somewhere else, but I can't find any sort of mold or pattern to where its expecting this favicon to be. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Regards.

Comment: Does the deployment really fail because of this or is it just an error you could ignore? favicon.ico in the root directory is a known convention some browsers follows no matter what. Any website that doesn't have it can expect numerous 404 in its logs. But nothing to worry.

Comment: It does fail, an application error message is shown instead of my index.html. Also, I did try putting the favicon.ico in the root directory (same level as package.json), but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

first check start in packege.json if you use nodemon change nodemon to node and add node engine in packege.json file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "12.19.0"
},
```